# Bluebird promise chain error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I keep getting this error while trying to run Promise chain. I can see in log first step went trough, then second step too and instead of third step I keep getting this error. I can't see any recursions here.. Also I'm using mysql client for bluebird database connection.

```
Promise.try(function () {
        console.log(1);
        return validator.escape(data.cookie);
    }).then(function (cookie) {
        console.log(2);
        return db('cs_users').where({
            secret_login_key: cookie
        }).limit(1);
    }).then(function (userData) {
        console.log(3);
        if (userData && userData.length > 0) {
            console.log(3.5);
            if (userData[0].user_last_contacted > 0 && (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 10)) > userData[0].user_last_contacted) {
                self.contact(data);
                return db('cs_users').where({id: userData[0].id}).update({user_last_contacted: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)});
            } else {
                self.io.to(socketID).emit('contactError', 1);
            }
        }
    }).then(function(){
        console.log(4);
        self.io.to(socketID).emit('contactSuccess', 1);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log('Error while contacting: ' + e.message);
    });
```

Comment: The error could be with your `NodeJS` version. Can you please try upgrading it to a newer version and see if it is working?

Comment: What is your db object ? Can you log the value of ``db('cs_users').where({
            secret_login_key: cookie
        }).limit(1)`` ?

Comment: @DavidR my current version is 6.9.1 could it be too old?

Comment: @Sandra Not really.. However the current version is `7.3.0` though.

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine this is it http://pastebin.com/4tpwCNsQ

Comment: and still the same problem with 7.3.0 version @DavidR

Comment: Can you try to use `Promise.resolve` in your second `then`? Like `Promise.resolve(db('cs_users')…)`

Comment: as a debug technique, test this chain by starting with only the first promise, then first and second, then first and second and third, and so on.

Comment: that output in http://pastebin.com/4tpwCNsQ suggests `db('cs_users').where({ secret_login_key: cookie }).limit(1)` does not return a promise at all - not sure why Bluebird chokes on it the way it does, perhaps something to do with the `circular` properties in the return value - regardless, if it doesn't return a promise, using it in a Promise chain will give unexpected results if the function is asynchronous

Comment: it was 2 connections to database made by bluebird and I don't know how. Changed from mysql to postgre and it works fine now.